# Reshape each unique value in DataFrame to column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame similar to this:

```
  12 11 10
1  a  b  a
2  c  c  a
3  c  b  b
4  b  a  a
```

I want to create a column for every unique value in the DataFrame and the columns as values, like:

```
         a        b        c
1  [12,10]     [11]      NaN
2     [10]      NaN  [12,11]
3      NaN  [11,10]     [12]
4  [11,10]     [12]      NaN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), convert `MultiIndex` to columns and then aggregate `list` with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), last remove index and columns names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df1 = (df.stack()
         .reset_index(name='v')
         .groupby(['level_0','v'])['level_1']
         .apply(list)
         .unstack()
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
print (df1)
          a         b         c
1  [12, 10]      [11]       NaN
2      [10]       NaN  [12, 11]
3       NaN  [11, 10]      [12]
4  [11, 10]      [12]       NaN
```

Or convert index to column, so possible use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) by it and then use same steps like before:

```
df1 = (df.reset_index()
         .melt('index')
         .groupby(['index','value'])['variable']
         .apply(list)
         .unstack()
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
print (df1)
          a         b         c
1  [12, 10]      [11]       NaN
2      [10]       NaN  [12, 11]
3       NaN  [11, 10]      [12]
4  [11, 10]      [12]       NaN
```